# How do I properly checkout the file system using subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Could someone explain to me how to properly check out the trunk from the SVN via eclipse?

Setup:
there is a `/trunk/` that I need to check out in its entirety.  There are tons of sub-folders, ie 
`/trunk/a`
`/trunk/b`
`/trunk/c`
Each of them has different source files.  For example, folder `../c/` would have c++ code
folder `../b/` would have java code, folder `../a/` would be just config files, etc...

Question:
How do I properly bring the entire trunk into the eclipse via the subclipse when I use 'Checkout'?  Specifically, do I 
**1)** Import using  a New Project  Wizard
OR 
**2)** import the entire file system into the workspace

If 1) then what project type do I choose since my /trunk/ contains a conglomerate of different files pertaining to separate projects (even though .project is NOT present).  For example, if I choose 'as Java project', then how do I run 'c++' code and vice versa.  Or eclipse does not care and everything is contextual based on the perspective?

if 2) then how does eclipse know about inter-dependencies between the files and what compiler to use, etc.  How does Eclipse know how to process the files (Highlighting, code )

Also, regarding the 'import the entire file system into the workspace', are we talking about the eclipse's workspace or a folder that I can choose to import the files to, which may or may not be eclipse's workspace?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse generally wants projects to point to one thing.  So your "a", "b" and "c" would typically be 3 distinct projects in Eclipse.  You would check out each of them individually creating 3 working copies in the same workspace folder.

You can checkout trunk as a "Simple Project", but I am not sure there is any value in doing so.  You would then need to Import the each of the 3 "real projects" so that you have 4 total.  If these projects already have Eclipse .project files in them, this will generally be fairly easy to do.  Otherwise, it depends on the current state of the various Eclipse Import and Create project wizards and whether they allow you to do this on the fly or not.  I do not work this way, so I am not sure.

In my case, my trunk has a couple dozen Java projects in it.  Each of those has the Eclipse .project and .classpath files checked in to them.  I just checkout the individual projects.

Subclipse still allows me to do things like atomically commit changes for all projects in a single commit.  There is not a lot gained by having their parent folder checked out.